# My server is down, can ping/SSH but not Https

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, lets-encrypt

I'm sorry if this is a bit brief. My server is currently down after I did a sudo dist-upgrade. All my system settings are seemingly good. I can ping my IP, can SSH my server. However, I cannot https my server. I have permanently redirected HTTP to HTTPS and this is my apache log if I http my server:

```
[20/Jan/2018:16:45:55 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 574 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.108 Safari/537.36
```

However, there's no HTTPS log and there's no server/apache response thereafter.

On issuing 
    netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               
LISTEN      1152/sshd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               
LISTEN      1212/postgres   
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    
LISTEN      1255/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    
LISTEN      1255/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    
LISTEN      1152/sshd
```

And

```
sudo lsof -i:443

apache2 1255     root    6u  IPv6  22977      0t0  TCP *:https 
(LISTEN)
apache2 1262 www-data    6u  IPv6  22977      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
apache2 1263 www-data    6u  IPv6  22977      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
```

Now, I would like a suggestion on what could be the reason for server not being accessible via browser.

I have been downvoted for this.But I shall like to why I have been downvoted for this? I have given all possible details showing my 443 port is possibly open for incoming traffic and my apache is logging access for http. I would like to know where I'm wrong with this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Got it. I shall delete this question and repost it in the said forums

Comment: You can flag the question and ask the moderators move it so you don't have to delete it on one site and create it on another site. It also resets the question's score. For whatever reasons, the Stack Exchange network does not allow you to migrate it yourself. Also see [Author initiated migration to other SE sites?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, sorry for posting this question here. This question should probably be going to other SO forums.

Now, regarding the answer - in case this would help someone - the issue was with system reboot (updating required security fixes), the firewall (UFW) settings, it seems, automatically changes to allowing only IPV6 on SSL ports (by default). What needs to be done is to change the same to allow both IPV4 and IPV6.

Thanks again to the community and I regret posting the question in the wrong forum. However, I'm keeping this here for any reference and not deleting the question.

P.S.: In case if someone feels downvoting the question is unnecessary, it would be a good help if it's removed.